# Hierarchical(Multilevel) Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario where I have to call multiple objects concurrently, and each object will call multiple other class's objects internally. After the execution of all child objects, it should return result back to parent object and finally, parent objects will return result back to Main thread. It is basically two level multi threading. I do not know what I should take under consideration when implementing this scenario. I would really appreciate any and all guidance, preferably with some sample code.

I have attached a picture which gives a clear understanding of the scenario. 
[image: Hierarchical(Multilevel) Multithreading]

simplty i need to creatre a set of threads and each created threads have to create another set of threads . and also reqires controll over every thread at any time. hope its clear thanks again

Comment: You don't seem to have actually asked a question.

Comment: Hi all.. i need to create a number of threads and each created thread will have to create a set of another threads. And also requires control over each thread  at any time. hope everything is clear ,

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. All you've done is give some requirements of your project. It sounds more like you're asking someone to design it for you. That said, I'd look at the info in Alexei Kaigorodov's answer about fork/join thread pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand: Every parent spawns some amount of children and has to wait for all children (and children of children and so on) to complete?

In that case, each parent can spawn one thread per child and then use a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to wait for all of them to finish. Semaphores allow you to wait for multiple threads at a time.

EDIT: You mention four tasks.

ADD thread: Create a new thread, manage all threads in a list of their parent. Use synchronization to maintain that list because if there is no guarantee that only a single thread will ever touch this list.

PAUSE: Set PAUSED flag. That will cause the thread to `sleep()` or to `wait()`.

RESUME: Unset PAUSED flag. If PAUSE makes thread `wait()`, call `notify()` to wake it up.

DELETE: Set STOPPED flag, then remove from list, or wait until thread finishes before removing from list (depends on what you need). If thread might be PAUSED, make sure, to RESUME it first.

The flags must be used by the thread which is running a loop to determine: Whether to PAUSE and whether to opt out of the loop, thus STOPPING the thread. Something like this:

```
while (!isStopped)
{
  while (hasWork() && !isPaused && !isStopped)
  {
      // do work
  }
  if (!isStopped)
  {
     // either just sleep for a few milliseconds (easy way) or wait()
  }
}
```

Make sure that you don't spawn too many threads. You should rather let children wait than creating even more threads, if you already spawned more than `x` threads, where `x` depends on your OS and JVM. Play around with it. Intuition might tell you: The more threads the better, but that is absolutely false. Once you surpass a certain amount of threads, they are already using all your computer's available resources (such as CPU, memory bandwidth and hard-disk bandwidth). Spawning more threads than necessary to use all the resources will just add management overhead and slow down execution.

On modern systems, competing thread scheduling might be done well, but each thread still has it's price tag. Imagine, all threads want to access CPU, memory etc. at the same time. That creates contention and requires a very smart scheduler (smart enough to predict the future and who can do that?) to not cause any noticeable overhead.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks Domi, parent threads threads will have to wait for the completion of child threads , and the there is a need of controlling (add/delete/pause and resume )every  thread in any time.

Comment: @jobz I updated my answer. Hope, it helps...

Answer (score 1):

[ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) and [RecursiveTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) are designed for such use cases. See [fork-join tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fork-join)

Answer (score 0):

you can create the N parent Threads on the main object and after calling start on each thread object you can call a join on each object. The main object will block on the first one waiting for it to finish, once it has finished it will try to join the second, the third, and so on until the Nth, but they probably will already have finished and then the main will be able to finish.

Use the same approach in the relationship between parent and child. However it is not clear from your question what the child threads will have to do, you may need to provide some concurrency control among them depending on the task at hand.

Cheers.

Comment: @ prmottajr thanks.. my child threads suppose to read some script files one after another and execute the command it contains..

Comment: But are they going to read commands from different files? If so, there is no problem, but if they are supposed to read from the same file then you have to take care and use some synchronized block/method.